# AJAX: background color change function using array values not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I will try describe my problem as simple as possible. I have this AJAX call to GET an Json_encoded array. With the "aht_value" being retrieved I get a color background 
being drawn from green-ish to red-ish ( im doing a heat map). My values are being output correctly.

**The problem:**
My "colorMe" function . I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am putting all my functions in the wrong place since I am doing everything inside my "success" and after my FOR loop as you see below. However, if I replace "min" for 100 and "max" for 1800 then the colors get displayed.

thanks in advance.

Array from show.php:

```
[{
   "username":"OXGOR",
   "aht_value":"241",
   "station":"B20"
  },
  {
   "username":"AISAI2",
    "aht_value":"199",
   "station":"B21"
  },
  {
   "username":"CAPAP3",
   "aht_value":"NA",
   "station":"B10"
  }]
```

map.php - JS part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{ } , // do I need to pass data if im GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){

                        var min = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                                return isNaN(curr['aht_value']) || prev < curr['aht_value'] ? prev : curr['aht_value'];
                                }, 1000000);

                                alert(min); //not returning the correct number

                                var max = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                                  return isNaN(curr['aht_value']) || prev > curr['aht_value'] ? prev : curr['aht_value'];
                                }, -1000000);    

                                alert(max); //nor returning the correct number

                                //function for calculation of background color depending on aht_value               
                                function conv(x){
                                    return Math.floor((x - min) / (max - min) * 255);
                                }

                                //function for background color
                                function colorMe(v){
                                    return "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
                                }

                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                            var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                            if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
                                divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));
                            }//end if
                            }//end for  
                    }//end success
                });//end ajax   
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
</script>
```

`show.php`: where I use `json_encode`

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
    // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) 
    $userdata = $user[$username];
    //if AHT is null give N/A as value
    if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => 'NA',
                                             'station'  => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end inner if 
    //else give the actual value of AHT without the decimals
    else {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                           'aht_value' => substr($memodata['aht_value'],0,-3),
                           'station'   => $userdata['station']
                                            );
echo json_encode($result);
```

this works If I put min to 100 and max to 1800 manually in my colorMe function:
[what is suposd to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjnmN.png)

this is returning my the wrong colors as you see below whenever I use min and max calculation
[not giving right colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8XHn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `map` on array length, rather that on array itself. Furthermore, I would suggest you to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce) your array:

```
var min = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev < +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
}, 1000000);

var max = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev > +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
}, -1000000);
```

To set the specific background whether color is `NA`:

```
function colorMe(v){
  return v == 'NA' ? "#FFF" : "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. However, it is still not displaying the colors

Comment: Oh, I just realized your data might contain non-a-numbers. Pls check an updated answer. And print min/max values, came from those function, please.

Comment: If I alert min and max I get  1000000  -1000000. Also, thats the thing because in my array some of my aht_value have "NA" (which is NULL) so how could I give it a white background and the others the normal background calculation in my function. thanks again

Comment: I beg your pardon, shame on me, I did not get that data contains array of arrays. The updated version should work for initial task. Would you please restate what you want to do in case od `NA` values?

Comment: I applied your new solution however it does not return the correct values in either min or max when I use alert. alert(min) returns 213 which is the second lowest in the array and alert(max) returns 97 which is the lowest in the array. The current max value in my array is 703. thanks

Comment: the colors are now being shown I put everything before my FOR loop. However, their not being matched with the proper value since the solution you gave me arent returning the proper value as I mentioned in my previous comment. thanks

Comment: Would you share your data, please. Because on my side it works perfectly with the example data you provided.

Comment: I updated the code and posted the image links to clarify what I mean. Tell me if its helps you understand. thanks again appreciate your help!

Comment: You said “it does not return proper min/max values” while I’m pretty sure it does. So until you have your data shared, neither could prove he’s right.

Comment: heres the data, link to the current array I have: http://pastebin.com/dr9tHq7p   it returns me MIN 1036 and MAX 984. thanks

Comment: Aha. You have strings in your data, not numbers, in aht_value position. Please see updated answer (the code now explicitely casts `aht_value`s to int using `+`.)

Comment: oh wow its working! could you explain what "+" does and also why the data.length I was using wasnt efficient to use even though it works? Now, if you dont mind I want to put a white color background whenenver the aht_value is "NA" . Thanks a lot for your help,  I learn new stuff!

Comment: Don’t you mind to read my previous comment? It clearly states what `+` is used for. Will update an answer for background.

Comment: oh I see it casts them, taking note of that!!

Comment: thanks a lot I appreciate your help as I was stuck for days! really helpful :) !!! I would rate you 100/10 if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Your array is missing a comma after the first object.

Comment: If (s)he uses `json_encode()`, probably only an error when copying it here from the function.